# Can you reverse the order of a column of text in vim?

Tags: vim

More generally could a column of text selected in visual mode be sent to the shell for editing?

Given some text:

```
a 5 z
b 24 z
c 3 z
d 2 z
e 1 z
```

If I highlight the center column of text, in visual mode and shell it out, it affects the entire lines.

`:'<,'>!tac`

gives:

```
e 1 z
d 2 z
c 3 z
b 24 z
a 5 z
```

However my desired output is:

```
a 1 z
b 2 z
c 3 z
d 24 z
e 5 z
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do that.

With this exact sample, you should be able to do it like this…

1. Place the cursor on the `a`.
2. Enter visual-block mode with `<C-v>`.
3. Extend the selection downward to the `e` and rightward to also include the column of spaces.
4. Cut the selection.
5. Do `:'<,'>!tac`.
6. Place the Cursor on the `1`.
7. Press `P` to put the column you just cut back in place.

This is only possible because all lines have the same content in field 3. If field 3 was different on some lines you would have to cut "column 1" to some register, cut "column 3" to another register, run your filter, then put back the two columns. Note that applying that method to your example would lead to something less than ideal because of the unevenness of column 2:

```
a 1 z  
b 2  z 
c 3 z  
d 24z  
e 5 z
```

It could be mitigated, of course, but by adding even more ad-hoc steps to the already less than elegant process. YMMV.